A strengthening of an inequality for posets by Chan-Pak
Suppose that $P$ is a poset, $x$ and $y$ are two minimal elements of $P$, and that $e(P)$ denotes the number of linear extensions of $P$. Chan and Pak use their recent combinatorial atlas technology in Correlation inequalities for linear extensions to prove that
$$\frac{e(P)e(P-\{x,y\})}{e(P-x)e(P-y)}\le 2.$$
The upper bound is achieved, for example, when $P$ is the linear sum of an antichain of size two with an arbitrary chain.
Question: If we further suppose that there does not exist an element $z\in P$ which (i) covers both $x$ and $y$ and (ii) does not cover any other elements of $P$, then is it true that the upper bound above can be strengthened to $\frac{3}{2}$? Is there an easy counterexample?
Some Motivation:
At first I thought that one might be able to improve the upper bound of $2$ by some expression that depends on the number of minimum elements of $P$, however if you take the disjoint union of the example above with an antichain you get posets for which the left hand side gets arbitrarily close to $2$ (as the size of the chain gets arbitrarily large).
If we look at the special cases where $P$ is a tree then the corresponding upper bound is $\frac{h-1}{h-2}$, where $h$ is the size of the smallest subtree containing $x$ and $y$ (h here is for hook length of the meet of $x$ and $y$). Similarly for posets that are Young diagrams of size $n$ the ratio becomes $\frac{n}{n-1}\cdot\frac{(h-1)^2}{h(h-2)}\le \frac{h-1}{h-2}$, where, again, $h$ is the hook length of the meet of $x$ and $y$. These observations seem to suggest that the upper bound could depend on some function depending on some hook-length type quantity associated to $(x,y)$. The question above is ruling out the situation where $x$ and $y$ are part of a hook of length $3$, and naively expecting the upper bound to move to $\frac{4-1}{4-2}$.
